# RDP client (mstsc) can't log in to any server

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, authentication, windows-authentication

RDP Client suddenly stopped logging in to any RDP server.

I'm sure that my credentials are right; I can log in via Remmina on Linux, but can't do it on Windows
 native TSC.

I tried to remove recently installed update of RDP (KB2592687), but it did not work.

I tried to reset all RDP settings (both `Default.rdp` and registry branch), but it still doesn't work.
I'm sure that ports are open because I can log in via Remmina, but causing authentication error on Windows.

How can I fix my client? Where can I view logs of my RDP client?

It asks me to enter username and password. When I enter them, it says that they are wrong and asks me for them again. This is the window that is displayed:

[image: RDP authentication window].

Sorry for the Russian language;
it says, "Log in attempt failed" and it asks username and password again.

Comment: What happens when you try to connect? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: When I enter my username and password, I get a message "Log in attempt failed" and it asks username and passwords again.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 sorry, I forgot to mention you. Please see comment above.

Comment: You probably have to provide a domain that the username is a member of to authenticate the session. Click "Use another account" where you'll be able to provide a username and password. The username is normally in the format `domain\username`.

Comment: @BigChris all my computers aren't in domain. They don't use it.

Comment: Ok, then you need to provide the remote computer name with the remote username: e.g. `Remote1\user`

Comment: @BigChris, I tried it, but took no effect at all. Still can't log in.

Comment: Try `10.10.50.2\your.username`

Comment: @BigChris still doesn't work. It seems that I have some problems with my RDP client, not with specifying credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

There was some wrong settings of firewall of my gateway server.

There was two lines in `iptables` config that allowed me to access my home computer from external networks:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.x.y
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.x.y
```

I did not specify any conditions (like in/out interfaces and ip addresses), so my server prerouted me to myself and Windows got surprised.

I have commented out these two lines and RDP started to work fine.